# Bypass prepared statements?

Tags: sql-injection, java

I know that prepared statements are used to handle input at the front end. However I was wondering how do you bypass a prepared statement? I have seen some people talk about string concentration but I’m not sure.

The language I’m using is Java so I was wondering how someone can bypass a prepared statement. I know it’s possible but not sure how exactly. An example would be nice to clarify.

Comment: Bypassing prepared statements is not possible so long as they are used properly. Is there anything in particular you had in mind?

Comment: @Conor Mancone it’s for an assignment. Some people have talked about using wildcards and string concentration but that’s for filtering bypassing. I was just curious if there is a way or flaws?

Comment: Not in prepared statements. They are a very effective way of stopping SQLi. Any vulnerabilities stem from failure to use prepared queries, or failure to use them properly

Comment: As @ConorMancone said, you can't bypass prepared statement, but it's possible that the particular implementation of the prepared query are buggy or insufficiently constrained, but that's not bypassing prepared statement, but rather a problem with the statement being prepared. For example, an application might intend to only allow you access to objects that belongs to you, but the query doesn't limit you from passing ids for objects that you don't own.

Comment: @user218030 For this assignment, if the teacher tells you what the answer should have been afterwards, be sure to post an answer to the question!

Comment: Thanks guys! We had to create a prepared statement and meta character filtering for a database and now we have to check ways to bypass it. I know meta characters can be bypassed, but not sure about prepared.